# How to run two for loops at the same time and make a decision off output

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, for-loop

I am trying to run two for loops at the same time in and make a decision from each pass. The loops search through a sql file and grab each line for comparison.

I've tried weaving the loop together with no luck. If anyone has suggestions on how to do this or how to implement a multi threading approach. (I have never tried multi threading)

```
for row in rows:
    print(row)
    KnowNextRow = nextrowfinder(str(row))
    print(KnowNextRow)

for perrow in perrows:
    PerfectNextRow = perrow
    print(str(PerfectNextRow))
Search_Procedure(str(row))

#Then compare see if  KnowNextRow == PerfectNextRow after each pass else:     {Code}
```

What I get if I were to run this with an if statement would be a decision from the last row pulled from the for loop. What I would like to do is compare every line and make a decision on a line by line basis.

Comment: What stops you from nesting the loops?

Comment: Can you provide an input and expected output within the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need multithreading to get the result you are after. Just put the output into Python lists and loop through using the enumerate function:

```
rows_list = []
perrows_list = []

for row in rows:
    print(row)
    KnowNextRow = nextrowfinder(str(row))
    rows_list.append(KnowNextRow)

for perrow in perrows:
    PerfectNextRow = perrow
    xx = (str(PerfectNextRow))
    perrows_list.append(xx)
rows_len = len(rows_list)  #Get length of lists to ensure they are the same
perlen = len(perrows_list) 

for idx, item in enumerate(rows_list):
    if idx < (perlen - 1) # Check that perrows item exists
        if item == perrows_list[idx] 
            print("Rows Match At Row# " + idx)
```

Comment: When I try this method I receive a list out of range error.

Comment: Are both lists the same length?

Comment: I edited the code to accommodate different size lists. That's all  I can do without seeing the rest of your code.